# appendTo jquery add value to input

Tags: php, jquery, appendto

how to add this value to input name value to print values as input to help me with forms

```
$('<textarea/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
```

> < input type='text' name='photo[]' value=''/>

i need to get our as   < input type='text' name='photo[]' value='file.jpg'/>

can any one help me with it that

full code

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = (window.location.hostname === 'server/php/' ||
                window.location.hostname === 'server/php/') ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<textarea/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i try but when i set input  and textarea  but i need value as < input type='text' name='photo[]' value='file.jpg'/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I doubt you wanna append a textarea, so replace that with the real element you want to append ()...and append it to the formm...
So if your html looks like this..

```
<form id="files" action="" method="">
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Then the code will be...

```
 done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<input type="text" name="photo[]" />').val(file.name).appendTo('#files');
        });
    },
```

Or try this...

```
 done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<input type="text" name="photo[]" value='+file.name+'/>').appendTo('#files');
        });
    },
```

Comment: see i need it out of   file.name  insert into value of input  as    <input type="text" name="photo[]" value=file.name />

Comment: my form <form><input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" id="fileupload"></form>

Comment: i don't replace form i need result of files uploaded insert into value of inputs

Comment: Yeah, I get that....whats the problem then???   is file.name even valid then?  what happens if you console.log(file.name) does it actually show the filename?

Comment: out was   <input type="text" name="photo[]" value="file.name">  not  <input type="text" name="photo[]" value="image.jpg">

Comment: out like   <input type="text" name="photo[]">   i need insert that val to  input value

Comment: Well then your file.name isn't a valid data structure....console.log(file.name) to make sure you are actually getting a name out, and not an empty string or null

Comment: OK try my new code, if that doesn't work, its definitely a problem with file.name, either being invalid, or empty

Comment: can you help me with it ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039583/preg-match-all-srting-from-file-with-value

Answer (score 0):

use .val() instead of .text()

```
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<input type="text"/>').val(file.name).appendTo('#files');
        });
    },
```

EDIT: Proof of concept as jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b26tx/

Comment: out like <input type="text"> i try to make it as input type="text" name="photo[]" value="image.jpg">

Comment: The append is working for him, its the file.name he is having trouble with....I told him to console.log it to see if its empty or whatever since my code above is appending but not setting the value, it tells me file.name is either invalid or empty