# preg_match_all string from file with value

Tags: php, html-select, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I need to search into file name lll.php  about content of option by value

as

my file lll.php

```
<option value="n-7069">1</option>
<option value="n-7066">3</option>
<option value="n-7065">2</option>
```

I try this code but not work with me

my search code  like n-7065

```
$ccc2=$rd33fddf33do['contery'] ;
```

my file content value

```
$llll= file_get_contents('lll.php');
```

but it now work with me

```
preg_match_all('|<option *?</option>|ms', $llll, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $select) {
    preg_match_all('|value='.$ccc2.'|', $select, $matches2);
    var_dump($matches2[1]);
}
```

Comment: please any one help me to get our 1 or 2 or 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('#<option value="'.$ccc2.'"(.*?)>(.*?)</option>#im', $llll, $body); 
print_r($body[2]);
```